# Camelot mportError: cannot import name 'PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed' from 'pdfminer.pdfpage'

Tags: python, pdf

**After install package**:
So the problem that dependency just always install new versions of packages.

```
import camelot
ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed' from 'pdfminer.pdfpage' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfpage.py)
```

Answer (score 3):

If somebody has a similar problem after build project.

You should to do `pip install pdfminer.six==20200517` it's install an older version.

So pdfminer was updated and package camelot stopped works.

Issue: https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/169